# Duplicate folders in network share

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows 7 machine that is seeing duplicate folder entries in a network share. The share is hosted on a Server 2012 R2 machine and the duplicate entries do not appear locally on the server or on any other machine on the the network.

Initially creating a new profile for the affected user resolved the issue but now its happening again and I'm at a loss.

Note: Not every folder is duplicated, maybe 1 in 20 is.

Comment: You might add a screen shot or something to show what you see exactly as a visual may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might have Offline Availability configured for this share, which caches the
files touched by the user.

To disable this feature, see the Microsoft article
[Configure Offline Availability for a Shared Folder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755136(v=ws.11).aspx).